# Botão starta na lateral e não embaixo da mat-table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-6

Tenho esse html

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div>
  <table mat-table [dataSource] = "dataSource" class="mat-elevation-z8">

     <ng-container matColumnDef="codigo">
       <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Codigo </th>
       <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oper"> {{oper.operatorId}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="nome">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Nome </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let oper"> {{oper.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let oper; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
</div>
```

Quando renderizo o botão Teste fica na lateral esquerda, mas ao lado da **Table** e não embaixo. Como resolvo?

Comment: você pode tentar colocar a class="row" nas divs que envolvem a tabela e o botão para que o bootstrap renderize como linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Para usar o Grid do Bootstrap vc precisa usar as classes do framework. Tanto na Tabela quanto nas `divs` onde vc coloca os seus componentes.

> Rows must be placed within a `.container` (fixed-width) or `.container-fluid` (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
>
> Use `rows` to create horizontal groups of columns.
>   Content should be placed within columns, and only `columns` may be immediate children of rows.

*As linhas devem ser colocadas dentro de um `.container` (largura fixa) ou `.container-fluid` (largura total) para alinhamento e preenchimento adequados.*

*Use `rows` para criar grupos horizontais de colunas.
O conteúdo deve ser colocado dentro de colunas e somente `cols` podem ser filhos imediatos de `.rows`.*

Veja no modelo abaixo as classes que usei para formatar o layout das `divs`

Documentação oficial da tabela https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables

Documentação oficial do Grid https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

```html
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="com-xs-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>#</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Username</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>Mark</td>
                            <td>Otto</td>
                            <td>@mdo</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>Jacob</td>
                            <td>Thornton</td>
                            <td>@fat</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>Larry</td>
                            <td>the Bird</td>
                            <td>@twitter</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```